# Join Query - MS Access

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have two tables as Table 1 [ Invoice No, Invoice Date, Customer Name, Grand total] and Table 2 [Payment Date, Customer Name , Payment Received , Balance Amount ] , trying to create a monthly report where wanted to join both tables such that it shows date wise transaction whether invoice is created or payment is received or both. Please help to write query.
Example

Insert Into report_invoice Values('INV/17-18/0001','08/08/2017','Customer 1','500')

Insert Into report_invoice Values('INV/17-18/0002','27/08/2017','Customer 2','600')

Insert Into payment_customer Values('27/08/2017','Customer 1','100','400')

Insert Into payment_customer Values('27/08/2017','Customer 1','200','100')

Insert Into payment_customer Values('28/08/2017','Customer 2','200','400')

[Table 1 - Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLUPd.png)

[Table 2 & Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrEvp.png)

Query Tried so far

```
select t2.inv_no,t2.inv_date,t2.pname,t2.grand_total,t1.pay_date,t1.pay_amt,t1.bal_amt from payment_customer t1 left join report_invoice t2 on t1.pay_date= t2.inv_date
```

Comment: Do Not put the data in a image.

Comment: Edited Question with Sample Data ..

Comment: Joining on invoice and payment dates makes no sense. The only link between these tables is customer. Cannot summarize payments by invoice. All you can do is  calculate total invoices and total payments, grouping by customer for both, and the difference is net balance for each customer. Why are you showing incomplete INSERT statements?  Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: Select * from
(
Select t1.inv_no,t1.inv_date,t1.pname,t1.grand_total , t2.pay_date,t2.customer_name,t2.pay_amt,t2.bal_amt from report_invoice t1
LEFT  join payment_customer t2 on t1.inv_date = t2.pay_date and t1.pname = t2.customer_name
UNION ALL
Select t2.inv_no,t2.inv_date,t2.pname,t2.grand_total ,  t1.pay_date,t1.customer_name,t1.pay_amt,t1.bal_amt  from payment_customer t1 
LEFT  join report_invoice t2 on  t1.pay_date = t2.inv_date where t2.inv_date is null ) as v order by IIF(IsNull(v.inv_date),v.pay_date,v.inv_date)More close what I wanted I want to satisfy join condition only once